# Are there characters that I need to escape in the ProcessStartInfo.Arguments?

Tags: c#, docker, process, docker-machine, processstartinfo

I am using `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` to execute `Docker` commands. However, it doesn't work for some commands. Here is the code and the example commands that I am using. All these commands work fine when executed on the `Docker Toolbox` command line.

**Commands:**

1. string command = "docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 4096 devmachine"
2. string command = "docker-machine ip devmachine"
3. string command = "eval $(docker-machine env devmachine)"

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
   psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
   psi.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe";
   psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox";
   psi.Arguments = @"--login -i ""C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"" " + command;
   psi.UseShellExecute = false;
   psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
   Process process = Process.Start(psi);
   ```

Only the 3rd command is not working, the 1st and 2nd works fine. I am wondering if there are strings that need to be escaped for the 3rd command. Only the 3rd command has the `$`, `(` and `)` characters

Comment: which version of .NET and VS are you using ?

Comment: @Vignesh.N .NET 4.5.2, VS 2015

Comment: can you try adding @ before your string like `string command = @"eval $(docker-machine env devmachine)"`

Comment: @Vignesh.N still does not work. as far as I know `@` escapes `/` backslashes. I'm really not sure about `$` and parentheses

Comment: prefixing `@` indicated a verbatim string, it does not escape anything and includes everything between the `"` and `";` as part of the string. exception being `"` itself. What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: can you try this `string command = @"eval ""$(docker-machine env devmachine)""";`

Comment: @Vignesh.N I have tried this also, enclosing the `$(docker-machine env devmachine)` within quotes. I don't have any error whatsoever. If I have, I'll be able to catch them with the `RedirectStandardError`. I'm really thinking that the command may have been changed somewhere before it reaches the Docker Toolbox bash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125487/discussion-between-vignesh-n-and-jmc).